# How to convert an Array of Object properties to camelCase which comes as dynamically from the response

Tags: arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6, camelcasing

I have a response which comes something like below,

```html
[
   {
      Name: "First Field Value", Second Field Name: "Second Field Value", Third Field Name: "Third Field Value"
   },
   {
      First Object Field: "First Field Value", Second Object Field: "Second Field Value", Third Object Field: "Third Field Value"
   },
]
```

I want to convert an array of object first elements(like Name, Second Field Name, Third Field Name etc) to camelCase. Can some one please suggest?

Comment: Please show us your attempt. There are countless examples of how to convert keys of objects and how to make a string camelcase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15) and the [_.mapKeys](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mapKeys) and [_.camelCase](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#camelCase) functions.

You'd run _.mapKeys on each object, and convert each key to camel case.

For example:

```js
let arr = [
   {
      Name: "First Field Value", 'Second Field Name': "Second Field Value", 'Third Field Name': "Third Field Value"
   },
   {
      'First Object Field': "First Field Value", 'Second Object Field': "Second Field Value", 'Third Object Field': "Third Field Value"
   },
{
      'works-for-kebab-case': "First Field Value", 'and_snake_case_too': "Second Field Value", 'AndPascalCase': "Third Field Value"
   },
]


let result = arr.map(el => _.mapKeys(el, (val, key) => _.camelCase(key)));
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```